# Failing to create GLFW window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I want to create a share GLFW window but GLFW is not able to create the second window.

i am able to create a single window but not two windows

This is my code.

I want to use the second window in another thread so i can share their context.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>

int SCR_WIDTH = 1920;
int SCR_HEIGHT = 1080;

int main()
{
  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


  // glfw window creation
  // --------------------
  GLFWwindow* sharedWindow = NULL;
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", 0, sharedWindow);
  if (window == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to create the first  GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }

  if (sharedWindow == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to create the second GLFW window" << std::endl;
    //  glfwTerminate();
    //  return -1;
  }

  while (true)
  {

  }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`share` is an input parameter. See [`glfwCreateWindow`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344).
Create the first window and call `glfwCreateWindow` a 2nd time for the 2nd window:

```cpp
GLFWwindow* wnd  = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", 0, nullptr);

GLFWwindow* wnd2 = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "window 2", 0, window);
```

The window can even be created in a separate thread, but note you've to ensure that the OpenGL context of the 1st window is not current when you create the 2nd window.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

GLFWwindow *wnd = nullptr;
bool wnd2created = false;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void wnd2func( void )
{
    GLFWwindow *wnd2 = glfwCreateWindow( 800, 600, "window 2", nullptr, wnd );

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        wnd2created = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    if (wnd2 == nullptr)
        return;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd2);

    // [...]
}

int main()
{
    // [...]

    wnd = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", 0, nullptr);
    if (wnd == nullptr)
        return -1;
    
    std::thread wnd2thread(wnd2func); 

    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
      cv.wait(lck, []() -> bool { return wnd2created; });
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd);

    // [...]
}
```